# cy.origin with Azure Active Directory (login.microsoftonline.com) doesn't handle the extra 'Stay Signed In' window

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cypress

I'm currently facing a problem with cy.origin and handling the extra window for 'Stay Signed In' that is sometimes displayed whilst authenticating.

I'm following https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication this guide from Cypress, and have it set up exactly the same, and it's running.

The issue here is that, whilst running this function:

```
function loginViaAAD(username: string, password: string) {
    cy.visit('/PRODUCTURL')
  
    // Login to your AAD tenant.
    cy.origin(
      'login.microsoftonline.com',
      {
        args: {
          username,
          password,
        },
      },
      ({ username, password }) => {
        cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
          log: false,
        }),
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

        cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, {
          log: false,
        }),
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
        //WE WILL NEVER HIT THIS LINE
      }
    )

    cy.origin('login.microsoftonline.com', () => {
      //WE WILL NEVER HIT THIS LINE
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    })

    cy.url().should('equal', 'PRODUCTURL')
    cy.get('#welcome-div').should(
    'contain',
    `Welcome ${Cypress.env('aad_username')}!`
  )
}
```

I can't for the life of me perform any other action to handle the window, which is only one click. I've highlighted in the function some commented lines of what doesn't get hit, which in my opinion it should.

After submitting the password I get '(page load)--waiting for new page to load--' as if Cypress is expecting it to now route us to the original URL (which would be the Product now signed in).

If anyone could provide any information at all as to why it won't perform anything else no matter what or where I put extra lines of code, I'd be very grateful!

I'm expecting to be able to perform extra actions inside the cy.origin function, I've tried debug lines to see where in the function gets hit but as soon as we've submitted the password it's expecting the new URL.